# How to add Scroll news in a Video using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, video

I am new in this area. I am trying to create a news scroll bar which will scroll over a video using C# . Where will I find necessary helps, or is it even possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can either overlay the video control with a transparent control or you can watermark the video with animated text. Have a look at Microsoft expression encoder, there's a free version.
But since you want to scroll news, you'll want the text to be dynamic, so you'll probably need to do an overlay.

Comment: Thanks a lot but Would You please give me some specific advice, because I really don't know where to start....

Comment: Solution depends on where you will be displaying the video? On your own website, youtube, windows forms application?